# undetected-chromedriver does not pass for

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I ran the code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
with driver:
    driver.get('https://www.ticketmaster.com/')
```

and I am still getting the `As you were browsing something about your browser made us think you were a bot` message. Are there special options I need to add? My main goal is to receive the `reese84` cookie value.

Comment: _My main goal is to receive the `reese84` cookie value_: code trials?

Comment: I am looking to build a webapp that records ticket availability and price. @DebanjanB